# How to move GWT HorizontalSplitPanel's splitter programmatically?

Tags: java, gwt

Is it possible to resize the west part of a `HorizontalSplitPanel`? If I reference the `SimplePanel` that is in its left directly and call `setWidth()` on it, then the splitter gets detached from the inner widget, because that should remain `widht:100%' inside..

```
<g:SplitLayoutPanel ui:field="splitPanel" stylePrimaryName="content-splitter">
    <g:west size="200" unit="px" stylePrimaryName="split-west" >
        <g:VerticalPanel styleName="west-panel" ui:field="westPanel">   
        </g:VerticalPanel>
    </g:west>
    <g:center styleName="center-panel">
        <g:SimplePanel ui:field="centerPanel" styleName="center-panel">
        </g:SimplePanel>
    </g:center>
</g:SplitLayoutPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setWidgetSize(westPanel, XXX)` and then call `animate()`

Comment: This is available as of  GWT 2.1

Comment: as I see in the sources, `animate(0)` is called from `setWidgetSite()`. Unfortunately the duration cannot be passed. :-(

Comment: Actually, this is not true. If you look carefully, the animate(0) will actually call the layoutCommand and schedule it for a later invocation (after the end of the current sequence call). If you call animate(500) in the same sequence call (javascript is single-threaded), you will modify the duration of the scheduled animation. Take a  look at the code of `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DockLayoutPanel.animate(int, AnimationCallback)` and `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.LayoutCommand.schedule(int, AnimationCallback)`